# Polymer test fails with "chrome failed to maximize"

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, js-test-driver

I create a POLYMER 3 test to test an element. If I run the test by command line in chrome, I get this message gefore the test fails:

```
chrome 71                Beginning tests via http://localhost:8081/components/@polymer/re/generated-index.html?cli_browser_id=0
chrome failed to maximize
chrome 71                ✖ app/test/search-input_test.html

  Timed out loading http://localhost:8081/components/@polymer/re/app/test/search-input_test.html
    <unknown> at   <unknown> at /components/wct-browser-legacy/browser.js:733:0

chrome 71                Tests failed: 1 failed tests
Test run ended in failure: 1 failed tests

chrome 71 (0/0/1)
```

in a firefox i receive a big JSON with this  content in the Message property:

```
"message": newSession
        Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
        System info: host: 'DESKTOP-HBA7M50', ip: '192.168.8.170', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
        Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        remote stacktrace: WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178:5 UnknownCommandError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:472:5
        despatch@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:283:13
        execute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:264:11
        onPacket/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:237:15
        onPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:236:8
        _onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9",
 "error": "unknown error"
```

Does someone can give me a hint, how to fix this?
Both browsers are up to date.